# Call AWS Lambda https end point from AWS IoT rules Engine

Tags: aws-iot

We have an existing ASP.Net Core API that we deployed in AWS Lambda. We were able to access the https verbs using AWS Serverless URL

Now we would like to access a specific https end point through AWS IoT rules Engine, basically invoke the AWS Serverless URL using AWS IoT rules engine? Is this possible ?

Comment: You could invoke a new Lambda via the IoT rule and have the Lambda make the call to the AWS Serverless URL.  What I'm not sure of is the "ASP.Net Core API that we deployed in AWS Lambda" statement (unless it was meant to say ElasticBeanstalk).

Comment: I meant an existing asp.net core API was deployed to AWS Lambda.Refer Link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/deploy-an-existing-asp-net-core-web-api-to-aws-lambda/

Comment: I meant an existing asp.net core API was deployed to AWS Lambda.Refer Link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/deploy-an-existing-asp-net-core-web-api-to-aws-lambda/ . Was wondering if I could directly call the serverless url from iot rules engine. But looks like I cant. I need to create a lambda function and from within lambda function call aws serverless URL.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the link, haven't tried that. If it is already a Lambda, is it possible to call the Lambda directly without going through the step of calling the API Gateway?

Comment: No it looks like we cant. AWS IoT rules engine does not allow you to call serverless URL directly. It can be done by invoking a lambda function which inturn calls a URL.